# How to use %EXPORT_TAGS

Tags: perl

I have a module something like this, in "lib", called Fool.pm, which is based on [the source code of CGI.pm](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/CGI.pm-3.49/lib/CGI.pm) (since that was the first module I thought of when I was thinking about exporting tags):

```
package Fool;
require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT_OK = qw/raspberry/;
%EXPORT_TAGS = (
    ':all' => \@EXPORT_OK,
);
1;
```

and a test script like this:

```
use lib 'lib';
use Fool qw/:all/;
```

I try to run the script and get the following:

> ```
> perl fool.pl
> "all" is not defined in %Fool::EXPORT_TAGS at fool.pl line 2
>   main::BEGIN() called at lib/Fool.pm line 2
>   eval {...} called at lib/Fool.pm line 2
> Can't continue after import errors at fool.pl line 2
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at fool.pl line 2.
> ```

I can't see what the mistake is here, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be a colon in your key. Also, I think the variables must be declared `our` in order to have it be available to `Exporter`:

```
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/raspberry/;

our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    'all' => \@EXPORT_OK,
);
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I actually copied this from [CGI.pm](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/CGI.pm-3.49/lib/CGI.pm), where there **is** a colon. I wonder how that error doesn't happen there.

Comment: @Kinopiko: I looked at the source code for CGI.pm and it looks like they implement a number of overloaded methods that handle the exporting process. My only guess is that the colons in the keys of original definition of `%EXPORT_TAGS` are there specifically to make `Exporter` __not__ handle them.

Comment: OK, I noticed there is some other stuff underneath there. Thanks very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: No, `our` just (lexically) declares use of a global variable; without it the variables are still global (but will give errors under `use strict`)

Comment: @ytsh: Ah. That's where I was confused; I only ever think of Perl code in terms of `use strict`.